# Ambiguous Column Reference with an AS alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias, ambiguous

I am unsure as to how to resolve an ambiguous column reference when using an alias.

Imagine two tables, `a` and `b` that both have a `name` column. If I join these two tables and alias the result, I do not know how to reference the `name` column for both tables. I've tried out a few variants, but none of them work:

#### Attempt 1

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM (a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id) AS x
```

This doesn't work as `a` and `b` are out of scope.

#### Attempt 2

```
SELECT x.a.name, x.b.name
FROM (a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id) AS x
```

SQL syntax doesn't work like that.

#### Attempt 3

```
SELECT x.name, x.name
FROM (a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id) AS x
```

That's just plain ambiguous!

I'm all out of ideas - any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

don't enclose it with parenthesis since `(a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id)` is not a complete query.

```
SELECT  a.name AS A_Name, 
        b.name AS B_Name
FROM    a INNER JOIN b 
           ON a.id = b.id
```

or (*assuming*) if you have longer tables names and you want to make it short,

```
SELECT  a.name AS A_Name, 
        b.name AS B_Name
FROM    longTableNameA a 
        INNER JOIN longTableNameB b 
           ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Is there any way of referencing both `name` columns with the alias? The examples in my question are simplified - I use the alias elsewhere in the query so need to leave it in.

Comment: i have updated the answer. follow-up question, why would you need to have an alias for both tables that have the same column name? basically you cannot do that. you need to create a subquery but first add an alias on the same column name so you call them easily.

Comment: Aha your second example gave me what I needed. I was basically doing a subquery on `a` again in the `WHERE` clause, equating columns in the first `a` and second `a`, so I needed the alias. Instead of aliasing the whole join I just aliased the first `a` which solved my problem.